# Facebook Private Message

Tags: facebook-graph-api, message, private

I am seeing replies to this same question with a NO answer, but they are a couple of months old. I am hoping that things may have changed since then.

Here is the situation. I have a program for managing rent (desktop app). I would like to have the renters sign up to receive private reminders into their Facebook inbox. I know that the user of the program would need a facebook account and the renter would have to be a friend. It seems that the API could check for these two criteria and then allow a private message between the two.

Sending email is easy and it looks like this is easily accomplished for Twitter. Can it be done in FB?

Answer (score 2):

For apps to communicate directly with users, Facebook strongly recommends you request the `email` permission (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) when presenting the user with the login dialog.

Once you have their permission, you can then email them from your app using the email field that is part of the `/me` object (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) in the Graph API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api).

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You can not send private messages to users in Facebook.  This feature would be a massive vulnerability for spam.  @DMCS's answer is the most feasible  - request the users email address with the `email` permission and send them regular emails.

Answer (score -1):

If the user has a Facebook username, rather than just a numbered profile, this should be easy, as their Facebook email address, which goes to their Facebook private message inbox, would be theirusername@facebook.com. (At one point, Facebook users had to opt in to these addresses, so I'm not certain if all Facebook accounts with usernames also have addresses, but many of them do.)

Comment: How would I find that username? I am looking at my FB profile and don't see a number or username. All that I see is the two email addresses that I have outside of facebook.

Comment: Try the Graph API Explorer tool at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer.  It will reveal your facebook user id.

Comment: If they have a username, it should be at the end of their profile URL. Graph API Explorer only reveals numerical IDs.

Comment: Not all users have user names.  This is not a valid solution.